# how to add an extended jpanel to jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I wrote a class that extends JPanel. 
Here is the code:

```
public class MedicalMonitorPanel extends JPanel{
    public MedicalMonitorPanel() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }
    public void initComponents(){
        //layout settings
    }
}
```

Now I want to add my panel to a jframe:

```
public class MedicalMonitorDisplay extends JFrame{
    MedicalMonitorPanel panel;

    public MedicalMonitorDisplay(){
    panel = new MedicalMonitorPanel();
    initComponents();
}
    private void initComponents(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    getContentPane().validate();
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MedicalMonitorDisplay().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

But I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at MedicalMonitorDisplay.initComponents(MedicalMonitorDisplay.java:53)
    at MedicalMonitorDisplay.<init>(MedicalMonitorDisplay.java:40)
    at MedicalMonitorDisplay$1.run(MedicalMonitorDisplay.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

which reports there is something wrong with the add() method. What's wrong?

Comment: A code sample would help.  Without, I would assume that the `container` reference is actually null as `add` returned successful (from what you've described)

Comment: `add(panel, getContentPane()); getContentPane().validate();` These are the methods I called in the class that extends JFrame.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with container reference cause I tried to use `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` rather than `A a = new A();`, it worked.

Comment: Why are you extending `JPanel`?  What does the (poorly named) `A` do that a normal panel cannot?  As far as code goes, please post a minimal example that compiles and shows that exception.  Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Why `add(panel, getContentPane())`??  Shouldn't it be `getContentPane().add(panel)` ??

Comment: Well, because I need to add multiple panels to a frame at runtime, I wrote a class that extends JPanel.

Comment: it doesn't work either if I use `getContentPane().add(panel)`.

Comment: `public class MedicalMonitorPanel extends JPanel{
public MedicalMonitorPanel() {
     super();
        initComponents();
    }
 private void initComponents() {
}}`
This is basically the structure of the extended class by now.

Comment: Please edit the question to add representative code of what you are trying to do, I think we'll be able to help you with your problem better that way. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I put my code to my question.

Comment: You're not showing what line number causes the exception.

Comment: The code you've shown executes just fine and produces an empty `JFrame`. It would seem the error is somewhere else - can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: @Jacob: the problem is in fact in code not shown and is due to using an array before it has been filled with objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SwingUtilities` instead of `EventQueue`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MedicalMonitorDisplay().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I would also follow *Hovercraft Full Of Eels*'s suggestion of modifying your code to add `panel` to the `JFrame` in the way he indicates.

---

**EDIT**

The problem was caused because of a missing instantiation of the `MedicalMonitorPanel` class when using a `MedicalMonitorPanel` array.

Comment: Sorry, actually, it is a field variable. Let me change it back.

Comment: It also suffers the same problem.

Comment: I'm running the code but don't get the Exception. Could you paste the stacktrace in the question? Maybe we can get some information from there. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot put the whole exception maybe because the restriction of StackOverflow. That's the part of my exception. Really thankful for your patience.

Comment: SwingUtilities doesn't work. I think there is something wrong with the class MedicalMonitorPanel, because if I tried to use `JPanel panel = new JPanel()`, nothing went wrong.

Comment: @Cacheing: If things are pointing to `MedicalMonitorPanel` in your code and we don't get the exception then maybe the problem lies in the contents of the `initComponents()` which we dont have.

Comment: "As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()`" —[`SwingUtilities#invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 3):

This makes no sense whatsoever:

```
add(panel, getContentPane());
```

Delete this line and start over.

Instead you should add the panel to the contentPane via:

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

If this still doesn't work, then tell the details -- what goes wrong if you try this?

Also, you can't call revalidate on the contentPane unless you cast it first to JPanel. But you shouldn't need to revalidate the contentPane anyway since you'll call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components, and that will suffice.

Comment: Um, it still doesn't work and I put the exception in my question.

Comment: @Cacheing:  you put the exception but that was with regard to your original code. Show how you tried to use my line of code, and if you get any exceptions ***show the line that causes the exception*** as well as the exception. We can't guess what's wrong -- you must show us.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.NullPointerException

 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)

 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)

 at MedicalMonitorDisplay.initComponents(MedicalMonitorDisplay.java:54)

Comment: @Cacheing: Again -- which line is throwing the exception. How are we to guess what line 54 is?

Comment: The exception is the same, and the exception still points to the `getContentPane().add(panel);` method. NullPointerException

Comment: @Cacheing: that doesn't make sense. There's more to this that is not being shown, and likely problems in code not being shown. Are you sure that you initialize panel *before* calling `initComponents()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15036/discussion-between-cacheing-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Comment: @Cacheing looking at the line numbers in the stack trace, you obviously removed part of the code. With the current code you posted, we cannot help you as it does not contain enough information

Comment: @Robin: the problem has nothing to do with the code posted and all to do with his trying to use an array that has not been filled with objects.